# require a JSON file throws a Node.js loader error "Error: Cannot find module 'example.json'" when running Babel transpiled code

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, babeljs, node-modules

There are several similar questions related to importing or requiring JSON (.json) files when building the code in TypeScript. My question is specifically about requiring a JSON file in an ES6 module that is transpiled to the current node target using Babel (core and cli). I see no config option like TypeScript's `resolveJsonModule` for Babel, which leads me to believe it should work without any config.

I am importing a JSON file (`example.json`) from a JS file (`index.js`) in the same directory, by doing:

```js
const myObj = {};
myObj.myJSON = require("./example.json");
```

I have also tried importing using the newer ES6 syntax as:

```js
import * as myJson from "./example.json";
```

I am using VSCode, and in both cases the auto-complete suggests to me the correct relative path to the JSON file in the source code.

The directory looks like:

```
src/
  |_dir/
    |_index.js
    |_example.json
```

In both cases, when transpiling with the `babel-cli` using the command: `babel src --out-dir build`, the produced build looks like:

```
src/
  |_dir/
    |_index.js
```

For some reason, the `example.json` file is not included, despite it being required in the compiled `index.js` file:

```
...

const myObj = {};

myObj.myJSON = require("./example.json");
...
```

As such, when running the transpiled build with node using `node build/index.js`, it throws the error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './example.json'
Require stack:
- ...
- .../build/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../index.js:15:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Here is the relevant configuration:

`package.json`

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir build",
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.8",
    ...
  }
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `import * as myJson from "./example.json");` contains a typo. Do you use a bundler? _"For some reason, the example.json file is not included, despite it being required in the compiled index.js file"_ `require` and `import` don't include anything. AFAIK Babel doesn't bundle. Have you tried providing the JSON file in the built project?

Comment: This was a typo only in the post, I have since corrected it. I do not use a bundler. I distinctly remember and have examples of projects wherein I `require` JSON files in the source code, use Babel to transpile (with the same config) without any bundler, and there are no errors.

Comment: But the transpiler won't include the JSON data into the source file. `require` and `import` will try to open and read the JSON file. It will work when there is a JSON file next to the generated source file. Try it. Copy and paste `example.json` next to the generated `_index.js`.

Comment: After checking again you are correct. The confusion was stemming from the fact that I was using `babel-node` to run the projects I mentioned, which does not produce a transpiled build and so somehow can reference the JSON files in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the boring answer is that Babel only processes JavaScript files. Anything that's not JavaScript (e.g. JSON) gets left behind, even though it "feels" like the JSON file is a code dependency that Babel should "just do the right thing with" (since you `require`d or `import`ed it) -- or at least give you an error or a warning. But that is not how Babel was designed in this use-case.

You need to do extra work to copy data files. I suggest three main alternatives to choose from:

1. Use a bundler like WebPack or Gulp which has tools for copying non-JS files around
2. Use Babel's `--copy-files` which copies everything. You can sprinkle in `--ignore` patterns to try to avoid copying things you don't want copied.
3. Use something like the `shx` npm package which lets you run Unix-style filesystem commands in a cross-platform way from inside package.json scripts.

`"build": "babel src --out-dir build && npx shx cp src/*.json dist/"`